# Warning: Attempt to present <ResetSigninDetailsViewController: 0x8ca9640> on <UINavigationController: 0x8ca44f0> while a presentation is in progress

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm getting warning like this Warning: Attempt to present ResetSigninDetailsViewController: 0x8ca9640 on UINavigationController: 0x8ca44f0 while a presentation is in progress!
and  also i'm sending an array to ResetSigninDetailsViewController in prepare for segue method,even the array in ResetSigninDetailsViewController is empty always...
 please give a better soluton thanks in advance :)

```
- (IBAction)didClickCantAccessMyAccount:(id)sender
    {


        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ResetSigninDetailsView" sender:self];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

      // when clicked the button the ResetSigninDetailsViewController have to be 
      load with getting array loaded in  that(ResetSigninDetailsViewController)


    }
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

    {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ResetSigninDetailsView"])
        {

            ResetSigninDetailsViewController *resetSigninDetailsObject =( ResetSigninDetailsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

            resetSigninDetailsObject.userDetailsArray = userInformationArray;

        //userInformationArray is an array in current viewcontroller

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you set the Segue to Modal? You're probably trying to present ResetSigninDetailsView as a modal view controller while you're presenting another modal view controller. Try changing it to Push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ResetSigninDetailsView" sender:self];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
```

Should be:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ResetSigninDetailsView" sender:self];
}];
```

Comment: the warning was gone but the array is still empty

Comment: Are you sure that `userInformationArray` isn't nil when assigning? Have you logged it?

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ResetSigninDetailsView" sender:self];
```

should be enough as long as it was a PUSH segue

Comment: but my segue is a MODAL